# How to make a children order randomizer with option to reset back to initial order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, toggle

I have several divs which content must often be randomized and back to their regular order within each of those divs.

I use a function like the one below for each one of those divs, with different class for each div, randomizing perfectly each div on page load. The random function works great, but I need to know how to get each div back to normal order by clicking a button and then back to any random order again, and I suppose it could be done by using jQuery's toggle method.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var parent = $(".randomONE");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
</script>
```

EDITED:

Andrei Gheorghiu, this is the html I used to test your first Answer.
It works great for the first DIV but not for the second one.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="randomizeChildrenONE()">RandomizeONE</button>
<button onclick="resetChildrenONE()">ResetONE</button>
<div class="randomONE">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let initialOrder = $('.randomONE').html();
function randomizeChildrenONE() {
  let parent = $(".randomONE"),
      divs = parent.children();
  while (divs.length) {
      parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }
}
function resetChildrenONE() {
  $(".randomONE").html(initialOrder)
}
    </script>

<br><br><br>


<button onclick="randomizeChildrenTWO()">RandomizeTWO</button>
<button onclick="resetChildrenTWO()">ResetTWO</button>
<div class="randomTWO">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let initialOrder = $('.randomTWO').html();
function randomizeChildrenTWO() {
  let parent = $(".randomTWO"),
      divs = parent.children();
  while (divs.length) {
      parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }
}
function resetChildrenTWO() {
  $(".randomTWO").html(initialOrder)
}
    </script>
```

I'm sorry I'm new and don't know how to do this better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The initial answer would have worked if you used different variable names for each case. But renaming the function to apply it to a different collection is not the way to go. I updated my answer so it works on multiple instances.

Comment: I updated the title of your question for better indexing.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot Andrei! I am very grateful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```js
$('.random-container').each((i,elem) => 
  $('.random', elem).children().each((j,child) => 
    $(child).attr('data-order', ++j)
  )
);

$('.randomize-children').on('click tap',  randomizeChildren);
$('.reset-children').on('click tap', resetChildren);

function randomizeChildren() {
  let container = $(this).closest('.random-container'), 
      parent = $(".random", container),
      divs = parent.children();
  while (divs.length) {
      parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }
}

function resetChildren() {
  let container = $(this).closest('.random-container'),
  children = $('.random', container).children().sort(
    (a, b) => Number($(a).data('order')) > Number($(b).data('order')) ? 1:-1
  );
  $.each(children, (i,el) => $('.random', container).append(el));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="random-container">
  <button class="randomize-children">Randomize</button>
  <button class="reset-children">Reset</button>
  <div class="random">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="random-container">
  <button class="randomize-children">Randomize</button>
  <button class="reset-children">Reset</button>
  <div class="random">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="random-container">
  <button class="randomize-children">Randomize</button>
  <button class="reset-children">Reset</button>
  <div class="random">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh it worked fine for one div, but I have plenty of divs on each file, so it only works for the first div in the file.
I'm looking for a solution that works on EACH div independently.

Comment: @rx65m, are there any other significant details you forgot to mention? Please update your question with a [mcve] which displays your issue. I need to see the markup this applies to in order to provide a working solution.

Comment: Thank you Andrei Gheorghiu. I just edit my Question in order to show how I tried it to work for 2 different divs. Hope this way is more clear for you. Sorry for not asking clear enough.

Comment: The whole point of programming is not having to write the same function twice, with a different name, just to apply it to a different collection. I updated my answer.

Comment: WOW! Now its working perfectly! Thanks a lot Andrei Gheorghiu you are not only a genius, but also very kind! I appreciate a lot your work and effort!
And yes I agree with you, I took the wrong path. Thanks again for your help and for the lesson!

Comment: Unfortunately this new code you kindly wrote, works fantastic, but only if the main Divs have 10 or less children divs.
With more than 10 children divs the RESET button can not bring the original order back.
I have more than 150 children divs, within each main Div.
Also using the RESET button before the RANDOMIZE one, will randomize the first children divs, but never recovers the original order back.
I tried different ways before bothering you again, but I couldn't find a way to make it work.
Here you can see this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/rx65m/9zkajtf1/
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @rx65m. Makes sense. It's because order gets parsed as string, not as numbers and when sorting strings `11` comes before `2`. I updated the sort function.

Comment: Thank you again Andrei.
This time it only resets the last children divs, while keeps randomizing the all the first ones.
Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rx65m/oazsqd58/

Comment: Sorry. I'm just learning to use Fiddle.
Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rx65m/oazsqd58/2/

Comment: Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/9zkajtf1/12/). Both the sorter function and the HTML needed adjustments.

Comment: Thanks again Andrei. I appreciate A LOT all your kindness, patience, work, and knowledge. I'm very sorry if I bother you. Thanks from my heart! It seems to be working PERFECTLY this time. All my kindest greetings and my warmest gratitude.